# Bootstrap Column with Equal Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve a 'grid' like display for my bootstrap app where the height of each row is the same (And the height is the defined by the tallest content).

[image: Goal]

However, am getting with the following code ([JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ab3f791t/)
) is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 1 Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      This is some long tex that has a greater height than the rest
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 1 Col 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 2 Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 2 Col 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 3 Col 3
    </div>`
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Output]

This is a simplified version of my app. In my real app, I get a big array of data back and I actually generate the HTML with React programatically, I I can not simply manually break up .row for every 3 col-md-4.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: add this class on parent row

Comment: I have tried this approach before. But it does not work in my case because my column does not sum up to exact 12. https://jsfiddle.net/gcpcu6xL/

Comment: Don't forget `flex-wrap: wrap`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22892773/171456