# Bootstrap Equal Height Column Breaks Responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve equal row height for bootstrap class using container, row and col-sm-4. Initially, I asked a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737498/bootstrap-column-with-equal-height?noredirect=1#comment74518919_43737498) which was marked as a duplicate. However, I am finding that there is a problem with the solutions provided.

The problem is that, in a normal three col-sm-4 situation, I get 3 rows in big screen and exactly one row when I reach the 'breakpoint'. However, the provided solution ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk3wubv6/)) breaks that rule. Depending on the screen size, I sometimes get 1, 2, 3 or even 4 columns based on the screen size as shown in the image below.

How can I achieve equal height while maintaining the standard behaviour for bootstrap?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 1 Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      This is some long tex that has a greater height than the rest
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 1 Col 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 2 Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 2 Col 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Row 3 Col 3
    </div>`
  </div>
</div>

// css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

https://jsfiddle.net/44mnaqxf/

If you read through the answers, a media query is needed to apply the "equal height" responsively.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Equal height using Jquery

```js
var biggesthei = 0;

$(".col-sm-4").each(function() {

  if ($(this).height() > biggesthei) {
    biggesthei = $(this).height()
  }

  if ($(window).width() < 320) {
    $(this).height() = biggesthei

  }

  $(".col-sm-4").css("min-height", biggesthei);
});
```

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  Row 1 Col 1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  Row 1 Col 1 Row 1 Col 1
    Row 1 Col 1 Row 1 Col 1
      Row 1 Col 1 Row 1 Col 1
        Row 1 Col 1 Row 1 Col 1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  Row 1 Col 1
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but jQuery is not an option really for me because I am using React and it is not best practice